# Md-content not scrolling

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-material

I trying to create a 2-column site with  and sticky header, but my  doesn't scroll normally.

### index.html

```
<body layout="column">
    <navbar></navbar> <!-- directive header -->
    <ng-view></ng-view> <!-- main view -->
    <foot></foot>     <!-- directive footer-->
</body>
```

### main.html

```
<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left" md-component-id="left" md-whiteframe="4">

    <md-toolbar class="md-theme-indigo">
        <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">Sidenav Left</h1>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-content layout-padding ng-controller="LeftCtrl">
        <p hide show-gt-md>
            Filters
        </p>
    </md-content>

</md-sidenav>

<md-content flex style="overflow-y:auto">
    <!-- Large text -->
</md-content>
```

### navbar.html

```
 <md-toolbar layout="row">
  <button ng-click="toggleSidenav('left')" hide-gt-sm class="menuBtn">
    <span class="visually-hidden">Menu</span>
  </button>
  <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools" layout-align-gt-sm="center">Hello World</h1>
</md-toolbar>
```

Comment: create a plunker for your issue

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/xrBpaIg53gHPT4wOUDfb

Comment: did you check the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your ng-view since you are embeding md-content inside,

```
 <ng-view  flex layout="column" style="overflow: scroll;" ></ng-view>
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/5LlKSyhVtR5OS8oIrMdO?p=preview)

Comment: It's not work for me: header and content in one group with same scroll, not only for content.

Comment: did you chck the plunker i attached?

Comment: @mummakill why do you need a scroll bar for the header? that is not a good design

Comment: I need one independent scroll for content with sticky header, but my scroll works for header AND content.

Comment: @mummakill the demo i attached is independent scroll for content with sticky header only

Comment: @mummakill only the index.html, mark it as answer if it has helped

Comment: How to make non-sticky footer in this case?